# asp.net dropdown list SelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: asp.net

We have the following code:

```
      <asp:DropDownList id="ddlIndustry" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIndustry_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Healthcare</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Hospitality</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

I then have

```
protected void ddlIndustry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        

}
```

If I put a breakpoint at protected void ddlIndustry_SelectedIndexChanged
it never goes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `AutoPostBack="True"` attribute to your DDL.